# Effect of CallerMemberName/CallerFilePathAttribute/CallerLineNumber on the performance

Tags: c#, performance, attributes, annotations

How does using of `CallerMemberName`/`CallerFilePathAttribute`/`CallerLineNumber` attributes affect the performance of application? Is this something that gets compiled in the application, or something related reflection, or something else?

I am planning to do something similar to this:

```cs
public void DoProcessing()
{
    TraceMessage("Something happened.");
}

public void TraceMessage(string message,
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("message: " + message);
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("member name: " + memberName);
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("source file path: " + sourceFilePath);
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("source line number: " + sourceLineNumber);
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=net-7.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This attributes are treated by the compiler, i.e. the `TraceMessage("Something happened.");` will be substituted by compiler to something like:

```
TraceMessage("Something happened.", "DoProcessing", "some_file_path", 6);
```

You can check out the decompilation [@sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

> Is this something that gets compiled in the application

Yes

> or something related reflection, or something else?

No, no reflection.